# Looking for the most efficient way to create hashes for 87 million records to put in a lookup table

Tags: mysql

Here's the situation:

- I have a table with 87 million records
- The table contains email addresses that have to be mapped to an md5 hash
- For this, we are creating a lookup table with the email and md5hash
- The data is live.

What would be the most efficient way to create these md5 hashes in the lookup table?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to do this?:

```
CREATE TABLE lookup (
 id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 email varchar(255),
 hash char(32)
);

INSERT INTO lookup (email, hash)
 SELECT email, md5(email)
 FROM bigtable;
```

It is efficient in terms of development time, code size, execution time, etc.  If the data is rapidly changing, something more sophisticated might be called for.  But for initial creation on a slow changing table, this should work just fine.

Comment: Since the tables are live, I guess hashing on the fly is already implemented, so using `INSERT IGNORE` would also help.